# Is this the most efficient way to write this MySQL Statement?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering the best way to write and execute this MySQL statement.

It worked 100% but my concern was the execution time and warnings.

After successful execution, it displayed:

```
12 rows in set, 65535 warnings (1 min 34.32 sec)
```

Well, I feel the guy got the job done eventually, but he had to scream so much to do it! (Lol). I believe there might be a less stressful way to perform this task.

Here is the complete working code:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datetime_t) AS month,

    (SELECT SUM(approved_amt)
      FROM table_20182019 AS total_all
        WHERE total_all.datetime_t <= table_20182019.datetime_t),

     (SELECT SUM(approved_amt)
      FROM table_20182019 AS total_sci
        WHERE total_sci.datetime_t <= table_20182019.datetime_t
        AND total_sci.id = 'S'),

     (SELECT SUM(approved_amt)
      FROM table_20182019 AS total_art
        WHERE total_art.datetime_t <= table_20182019.datetime_t
        AND total_art.id = 'A')

FROM table_20182019
WHERE x1 = 'ABC'
GROUP BY month;
```

So, how best can this be written?

Comment: It would help if you'd post your table structure, data sample, and a description of what you're trying to achieve with this. Us having to deduce all that from this complex query will only slow anyone down trying to help you.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but reasonably convinced as it currently stands it has a bug as if there's multiple entries in `table_20182019` for each month as the `SUM(approved_amt)` would imply then it's actually just picking whatever entry is easiest for the `table_20182019.datetime_t` which means it could pick the first, last, or one from the middle depending on any number of factors.
Telling us what you want will help us both ensure there's not a bug and make sure the results you get are what you expected.

Comment: Have you seen the warnings? What they tell about? Show us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the query by using conditional aggregate functions:

```
SELECT month(t1.datetime_t) as month,
  sum(t2.approved_amt),
  sum(if (t2.id = 'S', t2.approved_amt, null)),
  sum(if (t2.id = 'A', t2.approved_amt, null))
FROM table_20182019 t1
  LEFT JOIN table_20182019 t2 ON t2.datetime_t <= t1.datetime_t
WHERE t1.x1 = 'ABC'
GROUP BY month;
```

Comment: OK, let me try it out

Comment: Didn't work, I got this:
```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(t2.approved_amt),
  SUM(if (t2.id = 'S'), t2.approved_amt, null)' at line 2
```

Comment: OK. Some typos corrected. Try again. Your query has incorrect use of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: **Thank you very much** It works like magic and guess what the execution time was `12 rows in set (3.00 sec)` I knew there was an efficient way to solve that. Thanks @slaakso

Comment: So, the approach is great but it posses another formatting challenge like `14627955200` the `SUM()` is not printing the financials correctly. I tried `SUM(ROUND())` but its not presenting it in a readable format. Like `146,279,552.00`

Comment: Database fetches of the data for you. You do the formatting in the application side.